# Spring boot javax validation annotations are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project on spring-boot 3.1.0. I have a request dto that contains fields with validation annotations:

```
@Data
@Valid
public class RequestDto {
    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @Positive
    private Integer episodesCount;
    
...
}
```

I've added `Valid` and `Validated` on Api interface:

```
@Validated
public interface Api {

 @PutMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    void update(@PathVariable UUID id, @Valid @RequestBody RequestDto requestDto);
```

I added two dependencies to the pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

But the problem that it's not working, it still takes `-1` argument when it should take only positive ones. Why is that not working? I tried to put `Validated` and `Valid` on the `Controller` itself that implements Api interfact, also didn't help. 
UPD: I can't delete javax dependency since without it there are no `@NotNull` and `@Positive`. Also, tried to delete `@Valid` and `@Validated` everywhere except method parameter, didn't help. 
UPD: My controller implementation:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Controller implements Api {

@Override
    public void update(UUID id, RequestDto requestDto) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain what would be causing this, but you do not need to include anything other than the spring-boot-starter-validation jar, so remove the javax.validation:validation-api dependency.  Also, remove `@Valid` and `@Validated` references from everywhere.  Add only `@Valid` to the method parameter.  That alone will result in validation.

Comment: @lane.maxwell, you can't exclude `javax` dependency since `@NotNull` and `@Positive` are in there, if I exlucde it it shows them red

Comment: @lane.maxwell, I tried to exclude annotations Valid and Validated everywhere except method param, didn't help. I'm on 3.1.0 boot, it's said in the post. Will update with my controller impl in the post

Comment: No, if you're on spring-boot 3.1.0 then these annotations are provided through jakarta.  jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive, and jakarta.validation.Valid so you're using the wrong ones when you brought in the javax annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting `javax` dependency and specifying `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>` to `3.1.0` version helped.

Comment: thanks, this helped. and this was not obvious. i used all necessary packages and annotations. also @Validated on controller class is not mandatory

Answer (score -2):

Remove validation-api dependency and @Valid annotation on the RequestDto class ,try refresh maven.This might help you.